# Run on windows startup CMD with arguments

Tags: windows, cmd, registry

I need to run `cmd` with arguments on windows startup.  Is it possible to this do via a registry key?

I am trying:

```
"parameter"="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe\""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce\parameter]
```

But how can I add arguments to it, if that's possible?

I made this simple task `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c notepad.exe` but is doesn't work. What can be the reason?

Am I be missing something? I have made two records

```
HKLM / RUN/ "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c notepad.exe"
HKEY_CURRENT_USER/ RUN "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c notepad.exe"
```

`

The command doesn't start notepad.

Comment: It is, or you could add a shortcut to the Startup folder in the Start Menu.

Comment: yes if you add shortcut with command line in "start up" folder it will do

Comment: @Phylogenesis Thank you very much for your comment. Just I dont know the syntaxis to do it via registry key.

Comment: @user1627167 Do you know the syntaxis to do it via registry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example has the lines in the wrong order for a `*.reg` file. The following should work:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce]
"Terminal"="C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c parameter1 parameter2 parameter3 ..."
```

This will only run once on bootup. If you want to run every time you log in, then you need to change it to:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"Terminal"="C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c parameter1 parameter2 parameter3 ..."
```

Comment: I made this simple task "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c notepad.exe" But dont have notepad to be run by cmd. What can be the reson?

Comment: The Run/RunOnce keys in the HKLM hive are run on computer startup (before the login process).You will need to use the equivalent keys in the HKCU hive if you want it to be user-interactive.

Comment: Can I be missing something? I have made two records  1 in HKLM / RUN/ "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c  notepad.exe" 2 in HKEY_CURRENT_USER/ RUN  the same record "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c  notepad.exe" But the cmd doesnt start notepad

Answer (score 0):

from CMD you can Run this

REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce /t REG_SZ /d " "

or manually you can go to this structure and string value